# azure cli error while uploading

Tags: azure

while the below line was uploading the file we lost internet connection

```
az storage blob upload --file gentoo_root.img --container-name testcontainer --name gentoo_root.img
```

and hence stopped upload

the later on when i executed the above script again to start upload I got the following error.

> The specified blob or block content is invalid.

How to I restart the upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The specified blob or block content is invalid.

According to your description, this issue most like the **uncommitted block list** on storage is in a state that will no longer work with this command.

Maybe we should do those to solve this issue:
1.Perform a [GetBlockList](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list) (with blocklisttype=uncommitted) to retrieve the uncommitted block list, and **commit** the block list, then **delete** the blob.

2.Uplaod a blob to your container `testcontainer` with the same name `gentoo_root.img`, length zero, upload it to Azure storage account via [Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) (this tool only can be installed on windows). After that, **delete** that blob and use this script again.

3.wait 7 days for the uncommitted block list to garbage collect.

By the way, have you try to use another blob to test it? As a workaround, maybe we can use another blob name to upload it.

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: is it possible to do with GetBlockList with azure cli? I am not able to reproduce the issue. Renaming and other file were uploading.

Comment: @kumar For now, we can't do GetBlockList with Azure CLI, just API work. Do you mean you can upload your blob now?

Comment: @kumar If you need more help, please let me know. Also if it helpful, please don't forget to accept it as answer, thanks:)